# What permissions should a user have to expose a docker container port?

Tags: docker, permissions, puppeteer, alpine-linux

I'm setting up puppeteer on a docker container. Tried to do it according to their troubleshooting page https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-on-alpine.

But after creating and using the new user(pptruser) the server can't expose the port 80 because the user has no permission `Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80`.

**Can't find a clear documentation about the permissions that I should add to this user so that the user can EXPOSE $PORT**

Tried adding the user to sudo and that didn't work, but on the other hand even if that works I assume that's a mistake because it's a security risk.

Tried exposing the port before starting to use the new user, this failed too.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node

# Installs latest Chromium (72) package.
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    apk add --no-cache \
      chromium@edge \
      nss@edge \
      freetype@edge \
      harfbuzz@edge \
      ttf-freefont@edge \
      udev

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

# Tell Puppeteer to skip installing Chrome. We'll be using the installed package.
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

# Add user so we don't need --no-sandbox.
RUN addgroup -S pptruser && adduser -S -g pptruser pptruser \
    && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /app


ENV PORT 80
ENV HTTP_PORT $PORT
ENV HTTPS_PORT 443

EXPOSE $HTTP_PORT
EXPOSE $HTTPS_PORT

USER pptruser


CMD [ "run.sh" ]
```

run.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

PORT="${HTTP_PORT:-80}"

node "app/bin/server.js"
```

error from logs

```
 Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1258:19)
at listen (net.js:1307:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1403:5)
at appServer.app.then.then.then (/app/bin/server.js:69:12)
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score -1):

The error doesn't have anything do with your use of `EXPOSE`.

Traditionally [1], only the `root` user can bind ports under 1024, and in your container you're running as the `pptruser` user.

However, I think you'll find that doesn't matter for your particular use case. The port on which a service is listening *inside* a container doesn't have any relationship to the port on which remote clients connect to it.  The mapping of "ports exposed on the host" to "ports  listening inside a container" is controlled via Docker's [port publishing](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports) mechanism.

For your example, you would configure your service to listen on something other than port 80...for the purposes of this example, let's say you configure it to listen on port 8080.

When you run your container, map port 80 on your host to port 8080 inside your container:

```
docker run -p 80:8080 ...
```

Now you can access your service at port 80 on your host.  You can handle port 443 the same way.

Note also that the `EXPOSE` keyword in your Dockerfile is largely unnecessary.  In a typical Docker environment that is a no-op and is only informational. You can publish ports regardless of whether or not have have been `EXPOSE`d.

[1] The situation is actually [a little more nuanced](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NonRootPortBinding) under Linux.

Comment: Hey drive-by -1 voter, wish I knew what you didn't like about this answer!